# How to get text in a CATextLayer to be clear

Tags: text, ios, core-animation, calayer

I've made a `CALayer` with an added `CATextLayer` and the text comes out blurry.  In the docs, they talk about "sub-pixel antialiasing", but that doesn't mean much to me.  Anyone have a code snippet that makes a `CATextLayer` with a bit of text that is clear?

Here's the text from Apple's documentation:

> Note: CATextLayer disables sub-pixel antialiasing when rendering text.
>   Text can only be drawn using sub-pixel antialiasing when it is
>   composited into an existing opaque background at the same time that
>   it's rasterized. There is no way to draw subpixel-antialiased text by
>   itself, whether into an image or a layer, separately in advance of
>   having the background pixels to weave the text pixels into. Setting
>   the opacity property of the layer to YES does not change the rendering
>   mode.

The second sentence implies that one can get good looking text if one `composites` it into an `existing opaque background at the same time that it's rasterized.`  That's great, but how do I composite it and how do you give it an opaque background and how do you rasterize  it?

The code they use in their example of a Kiosk Menu is as such: (It's OS X, not iOS, but I assume it works!)

```
NSInteger i;
for (i=0;i<[names count];i++) {
    CATextLayer *menuItemLayer=[CATextLayer layer];
    menuItemLayer.string=[self.names objectAtIndex:i];
    menuItemLayer.font=@"Lucida-Grande";
    menuItemLayer.fontSize=fontSize;
    menuItemLayer.foregroundColor=whiteColor;
    [menuItemLayer addConstraint:[CAConstraint
         constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMaxY
                      relativeTo:@"superlayer"
                       attribute:kCAConstraintMaxY
                          offset:-(i*height+spacing+initialOffset)]];
    [menuItemLayer addConstraint:[CAConstraint
         constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMidX
                      relativeTo:@"superlayer"
                       attribute:kCAConstraintMidX]];
    [self.menuLayer addSublayer:menuItemLayer];
} // end of for loop
```

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Adding the code that I actually used that resulted in blurry text.  It's from a related question I posted about adding a `UILabel` rather than a `CATextLayer` but getting a black box instead.  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818676/adding-a-uilabels-layer-to-a-calayer-and-it-just-shows-black-box`

```
CATextLayer* upperOperator = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components1[4] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
CGColorRef almostWhite = CGColorCreate(space,components1);
CGFloat components2[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
CGColorRef almostBlack = CGColorCreate(space,components2);
CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
upperOperator.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"13"];
upperOperator.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
upperOperator.foregroundColor = almostBlack;
upperOperator.backgroundColor = almostWhite;
upperOperator.position = CGPointMake(50.0, 25.0);
upperOperator.font = @"Helvetica-Bold";
upperOperator.fontSize = 48.0f;
upperOperator.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
upperOperator.borderWidth = 1;
upperOperator.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
[card addSublayer:upperOperator];
[upperOperator release];
CGColorRelease(almostWhite);
CGColorRelease(almostBlack);
```

---

EDIT 2:  See my answer below for how this got solved.  sbg.

Comment: This will not answer your question, but may be relevant for someone like me who is only looking to draw attributed text, in a manner most similar to using UILabel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Short answer — You need to set the contents scaling:

```
textLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

---

A while ago I learned that when you have custom drawing code, you have to check for the retina display and scale your graphics accordingly.  `UIKit` takes care of most of this, including font scaling.

Not so with `CATextLayer.`

My blurriness came from having a `.zPosition` that was not zero, that is, I had a transform applied to my parent layer.  By setting this to zero, the blurriness went away, and was replaced by serious pixelation.

After searching high and low, I found that you can set `.contentsScale` for a `CATextLayer` and you can set it to `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` to match the screen resolution.  (I assume this works for non-retina, but I haven't checked - too tired)

After including this for my `CATextLayer` the text became crisp.  Note - it's not necessary for the parent layer.

And the blurriness?  It comes back when you're rotating in 3D, but you don't notice it because the text starts out clear and while it's in motion, you can't tell.

Problem solved!

Comment: This is the short answer: `textLayer.contentScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`  BTW, I like long answers too :)

Comment: This applies to any CALayer that is created programmatically. For example, if you notice images drawn into your CALayer are not crisp on the retina display, it’s likely this is the issue and solution.

Comment: Correction `_textLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`   You're missing an "s" ;)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I add a CATextLayer to a video (AVFoundation/AVMutableComposition) by AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool. The text still have aliasing.

Comment: there is no scale option in mac osx

Comment: @sangram-s The equivalent call on macOS is `backingScaleFactor` in `NSWindow`. There is also a `backingScaleFactor` property on `NSScreen`, but it's better to use the former as it's possible to have one Retina Display screen and another that's not.

Answer (score 45):

## Swift

Set the text layer to use the same scale as the screen.

```
textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

## Before:

[image]

## After:

[image]

Comment: macOS swift 4.2 version: (NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor)!

Comment: @roberto, don't force unwrap! Safe solution is: `textLayer.contentsScale = NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor ?? textLayer.contentsScale`

Comment: Solved it for me on iOS 16.2 on an iPhone 14 Pro Max.  I guess this is @Steve's answer ported from Objective C to Swift, anyway, differences is night and day between the blurry I had before and the crisp I have through that simply property assignment.

Answer (score 15):

First off I wanted to point out that you've tagged your question with iOS, but constraint managers are only available on OSX, so I'm not sure how you're getting this to work unless you've been able to link against it in the simulator somehow. On the device, this functionality is not available.

Next, I'll just point out that I create CATextLayers often and never have the blurring problem you're referring to so I know it can be done. In a nutshell this blurring occurs because you are not positioning your layer on the whole pixel. Remember that when you set the position of a layer, you use a float values for the x and y. If those values have numbers after the decimal, the layer will not be positioned on the whole pixel and will therefore give this blurring effect--the degree of which depending upon the actual values. To test this, just create a CATextLayer and explicitly add it to the layer tree ensuring that your position parameter is on a whole pixel. For example:

```
CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
[textLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 30.0f)];
[textLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(200.0f, 100.0f)];
[textLayer setString:@"Hello World!"];

[[self menuLayer] addSublayer:textLayer];
```

If your text is still blurry, then there is something else wrong. Blurred text on your text layer is an artifact of incorrectly written code and not an intended capability of the layer. When adding your layers to a parent layer, you can just coerce the x and y values to the nearest whole pixel and it should solve your blurring problem.

Answer (score 15):

Before setting shouldRasterize, you should:

1. set the rasterizationScale of the base layer you are going to rasterize
2. set the contentsScale property of any CATextLayers and possibly other types of layers(it never hurts to do it)

If you don't do #1, then the retina version of sub layers will look blurry, even for normal CALayers.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  CALayer *mainLayer = [[self view] layer];
  [mainLayer setRasterizationScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];

  CATextLayer *messageLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
  [messageLayer setForegroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
  [messageLayer setContentsScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
  [messageLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 170, 250, 50)];
  [messageLayer setString:(id)@"asdfasd"];

  [mainLayer addSublayer:messageLayer];

  [mainLayer setShouldRasterize:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do 2 things, the first was mentioned above:

Extend CATextLayer and set the opaque and contentsScale properties to properly support retina display, then render with anti aliasing enabled for text.

```
+ (TextActionLayer*) layer
{
  TextActionLayer *layer = [[TextActionLayer alloc] init];
  layer.opaque = TRUE;
  CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
  layer.contentsScale = scale;
  return [layer autorelease];
}

// Render after enabling with anti aliasing for text

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.backgroundColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, bounds);
    CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(ctx, TRUE);
    [super drawInContext:ctx];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you came searching here for a similar issue for a CATextLayer in OSX, after much wall head banging, I got the sharp clear text by doing:

```
text_layer.contentsScale = self.window!.backingScaleFactor
```

(I also set the views background layer contentsScale to be the same).

Answer (score 0):

This is faster and easier: you just need to set contentsScale

```
    CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    [label setFontSize:15];
    [label setContentsScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [label setString:@"test"];
    [label setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [label setForegroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [self addSublayer:label];
```