# how to do the formatting in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

how to do the formatting in a UILabel ? for exemple , if i want to make this , **Connected as** Keving G , "connected as" and "kevin g" have différents colors and size . Should i use 2 UIlabel ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/wader/ios-misc/tree/master/CoreTextLabel maybe could helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another potential solution, but these might be too complicated for your purposes.

You can use a [open source solution like OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) (which uses a NSAttributedString) or a CATextLayer which takes a NSAttributedString as well.

I got these answers from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring) (which includes sample code for OHAttributedLabel).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two labels and set font accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a UILabel.

One option is to use a UIWebView and stick HTML inside it...

Answer (score 0):

TTStyledLabel can be used from three20 library