# Display colorful text in iPhone

Tags: iphone, colors

Is there any way to display colorful text in iPhone `without using UIWebView`

Eg "red blue green voilet"

all in single UITextView, UITextField, UILabel or anything except UIWebview.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a NSAttributed string and then supply that to a CATextLayer or an open source library like [AliSoftware's OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

[Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring) that may help you out.

Comment: You might also like [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) which add some nice support for `NSString` as well as `NSAttributedString`. Also it a drop in replacement for `UILabel`