# How do I use multiple different UIFonts in a UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an UILabel in my UIView. The text of my label is dynamic: it's a web service call which returns to me the text that I will put in my label. Here's an example of the content of the label:

```
"this is an example of my text/nthis is the second line".
```

I would like to put the first line in a specific font (Helvetica-Bold 12px for example) and the second line in another font (Helvetica 15px for example). How i can do this?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I'd recommend using two separate UILabel instances, take your text and get an array via `[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]`, then place object at index 0 in the first one, and if you have a second object, put it in the second label.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a static `UIWebView` and simply wrap your text into HTML+CSS. This will be much easier than doing all the layout in code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is NSAttributedString. 
Here is a example: [iphone/ipad: How exactly use NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring)

Comment: Thanks, i think that all the solutions presented to me are good.