# NSString format like html tag <sup>

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, format

How I can print on UILabel text like this "m³"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString and UILabel do not have such advanced formatting. You can print ³ though, because it's a character. Which you can safely put inside an NSString like `NSString *symbol = @"³"`. To input other strings, click the U.S. flag at top right and choose Character Viewer.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the sup value by the unicode value 0x2081 or 0x2082 or 0x2083 means by changing last digit of 0x208

If you can print in uilabel m³ then follow the steps

const unichar ch = 0x2083;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"m%@", ch];
NSLog(@"%@",string);

It will print m³ what you want.

Then add the string value in UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

If superscripted digits is all you want, the easiest thing would be to use the [superscripted digits from Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf). You can put them in `NSString`, and use in `UILabel` without further modifications.

If you need more functionality, [you can use `NSAttributedString` with `OHAttributedLabel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869071/335858).

Answer (score 0):

For advanced formatting your best bet will be to use UIWebView:

```
UIWebView* webView;
// ...
NSString* html = @"m<sup>3</sup>";
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

But if you want to use only ³ etc. probably it's simpler to use the unicode characters directly.