# UILabel - Color specific characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I have a set of `UILabel`s that are automatically generated by my controller.  What I would like is to be able to colour individual characters different colours. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with a `UILabel`. The object usually used to encapsulate strings with formatting is an `NSAttributedString`, but they can't be displayed by a `UILabel`.

You'll have to use a `CATextLayer` instead, or one of a number of drop-in replacements for `UILabel` that accept attributed strings. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make a `UILabel` with different text colors. You can assign a certain font and certain background color to a UILabel. But you can do one thing. As follows.

```
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
      label.tag = i;
      [self.view addSubView:label];

  }

  for(UIView *view in [self.view subViews]){
  if([view isKindOfClass[UILabel class]]){
  switch (view.tag){
  case 1:

      view.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
      view.frame = CGRectMake(0,y,37,10);
      (UILabel*)view.text = @"Hello";
      [view sizeToFit];
      y=y+view.frame.size.width;
      break;
  case 2:
      view.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
      view.frame = CGRectMake(0,y,37,10);
      (UILabel*)view.text = @"World";
      [view sizeToFit];
      y=y+view.frame.size.width;
      break;

      //
      //
      }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow what the code does, what is it meant to do?