# Font color doubts

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uicolor, core-text

i have this code to set a DB(sqlite)text into my view.i just draw the text in view using core text..

NSMutableString *combined = [NSMutableString string];

```
for(NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < [delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish count]; idx++) {
    [combined appendFormat:@"  %d %@", 
     idx + 1, 
     [delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish objectAtIndex:idx]];
}

self.multiPageView.text =combined;
```

delegatee.allSelectedVerseEnglish this is the array...and between each sentence of the text i put numbers like this 1 haii this is nipin 2 haii this is stack overflow 3 etc etc ..like that..i am able to change the text color of all the text includes the numbers ..but i need to put "red"color to numbers .how to change the color of the numbers in the above code.is that possible?.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `NSMutableAttributedString` and set the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` value using the [`setAttributes:range:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: haii thanks for the answer...can you plz explain ..i dint know how to do this?

Comment: @stackiphone It's quite involved, but the answer to this SO question might give you a head start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: I see; you need to format the integer into a `NSString` using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intValue]` put that into an `NSAttributedString` and append it to the larger `NSMutableAttributedString` you are building.  As I said... quite involved.

Comment: i put this code,,but i got a warning that NSMutableattributestring may not response to settextcolor ...  NSAttributedString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", idx];
        [str setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: @stackiphone Follow the link to the example; you don't use `SetFontColor` you create an `NSDictionary` of attribute/value pairs that define colours, fonts and other stuff.