# Can I set the `attributedText` property of `UILabel`

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

Can I set the `attributedText` property of a `UILabel` object? I tried the below code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.attributedText = @"asdf";
```

But it gives this error:

> Property "attributedText" not found on object of type 'UILabel *'

`#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>` not working

Comment: Use this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: i think this is useful for u   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring

Answer (score 33, accepted):

<strike>Unfortunately, `UILabel` doesn't support attributed strings.</strike> You can use [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) instead.

*Update:* Since iOS6, `UILabel` does support attributed strings. See [UILabel reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText) or Michael Kessler's answer below for more details.

Comment: As of iOS 6, UILabel supports attributed strings via the attributedText property.

Answer (score 204):

Here is a complete example of how to use an attributed text on a label:

```
NSString *redText = @"red text";
NSString *greenText = @"green text";
NSString *purpleBoldText = @"purple bold text";

NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here are %@, %@ and %@", 
                  redText,  
                  greenText,  
                  purpleBoldText];

// If attributed text is supported (iOS6+)
if ([self.label respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)]) {

    // Define general attributes for the entire text
    NSDictionary *attribs = @{
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.label.textColor,
                              NSFontAttributeName: self.label.font
                              };
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = 
        [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                               attributes:attribs];

    // Red text attributes
    UIColor *redColor = [UIColor redColor];
    NSRange redTextRange = [text rangeOfString:redText];// * Notice that usage of rangeOfString in this case may cause some bugs - I use it here only for demonstration
    [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:redColor}
                            range:redTextRange];

    // Green text attributes
    UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    NSRange greenTextRange = [text rangeOfString:greenText];// * Notice that usage of rangeOfString in this case may cause some bugs - I use it here only for demonstration
    [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:greenColor}
                            range:greenTextRange];

    // Purple and bold text attributes
    UIColor *purpleColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.label.font.pointSize];
    NSRange purpleBoldTextRange = [text rangeOfString:purpleBoldText];// * Notice that usage of rangeOfString in this case may cause some bugs - I use it here only for demonstration
    [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:purpleColor,
                                    NSFontAttributeName:boldFont}
                            range:purpleBoldTextRange];

    self.label.attributedText = attributedText;
}
// If attributed text is NOT supported (iOS5-)
else {
    self.label.text = text;
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind using rangeOfString like this will cause bugs if some parts of the text are a subset of others. You'd do better to work out ranges yourself using NSRange and working out length of strings manually.

Comment: @owencm, you are absolutely right. This code can't be used in any situation - especially not when the texts come from the web. This code snippet just demonstrates how to use the attributedText together with backward compatibility...

Comment: Good answer.  But damn is that an _obtuse_ API.

Comment: @aroth , this is the way to do it in code and still support the older OS versions where this functionality is not available. If you support only iOS6+ (most of the apps today) then you may do it in the interface builder - much cleaner...

Comment: this doesn't work when you have same text more than once and apply different attributes .. :( you need to have unique strings.

Comment: @Ankur , as I've mentioned in one of the comments above, "This code can't be used in any situation - especially not when the texts come from the web. This code snippet just demonstrates how to use the attributedText together with backward compatibility..."

Answer (score 12):

```
NSString *str1 = @"Hi Hello, this is plain text in red";

NSString *cardName = @"This is bold text in blue";

NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",str1,cardName];


// Define general attributes for the entire text
NSDictionary *attribs = @{
                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                          NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]
                          };
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attribs];


UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0];
NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:cardName];
[attributedText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor],
                                NSFontAttributeName:boldFont} range:range];


myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

myLabel.attributedText = attributedText;
```

Answer (score 6):

for Swift 4:

iOS 11 and xcode 9.4

```
  let str = "This is a string which will shortly be modified into AtrributedString"

  var attStr = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: str)

  attStr.addAttribute(.font,
                value: UIFont.init(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold", size: 15) ?? "font not found",
                range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: str.count))

  self.textLabel.attributedText = attStr
```

Answer (score 5):

For people using swift, here's a one-liner:

```
myLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myLabel.text!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "YourFont", size: 12), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
```

Answer (score 3):

so,here is the code to have different properties for sub strings ,of a string.

```
 NSString *str=@"10 people likes this";
    NSString *str2=@"likes this";
    if ([str hasSuffix:str2])
    {
        NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];

    // for string 1 //

        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,str.length-str2.length)];
         [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14] range:NSMakeRange(0,str.length-str2.length)];
  // for string 2 //

        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange((str.length-str2.length),str2.length)];
        [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12] range:NSMakeRange((str.length-str2.length),str2.length)];
        label.attributedText=string;
    }
    else
    {
        label.text =str;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps ;)

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"asdf"];
[attrStr setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
lbl.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: Just use the code above and it should work. Nothing else to do.

Comment: gives an error: Property "attributedText" not found on object of type 'UILabel *'

Comment: Try importing "CoreText.framework". And then put in your .h file #import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

Comment: again the same error gives: Property "attributedText" not found on object of type 'UILabel *'

Comment: Then try using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: That's not how you use NSMutableAttributedString, so the code above will simply not work. A similar and simple example is on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11291275/67397

Answer (score 0):

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
NSDictionary *fontDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" v 1.2.55" attributes: fontDict];

UIFont *fontNew = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
NSDictionary *fontDictNew = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: fontNew forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStringNew = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@“Application” attributes: fontDictNew];
[attrStringNew appendAttributedString: attrString];
self.vsersionLabel.attributedText = attrStringNew;
```