# Different fonts in same UILabel

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios9.1

I have a UILabel with text

```
Choose Pasta: Fettuccine
Add Toppings To The Pasta: Side Meatball
Substitute Alfredo Sauce: Substitute Alfredo Sauce On Pasta
Choose A Complimentary Soup Or Salad: Zuppa Toscana
```

How do I apply different fonts Bold & Normal for this UILabel so that it displays like

**Choose Pasta**: Fettuccine
    **Add Toppings To The Pasta**: Side Meatball
    **Substitute Alfredo Sauce**: Substitute Alfredo Sauce On Pasta
    **Choose A Complimentary Soup Or Salad**: Zuppa Toscana

The part before : as Bold & the part after : as normal font

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: use attributed string ..

Comment: Check it out:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031623/how-can-i-use-attributedtext-in-uilabel> and this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an `NSAttributedString` and set it as the label's `attributedText` property.

Example:

```
let html = "<strong>Choose Pasta</strong>: Fettuccine <strong>Add Toppings To The Pasta</strong>: Side Meatball <strong>Substitute Alfredo Sauce</strong>: Substitute Alfredo Sauce On Pasta <strong>Choose A Complimentary Soup Or Salad</strong>: Zuppa Toscana"
let richText = try NSAttributedString(
    data: html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
    options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding],
    documentAttributes: nil)
label.attributedText = richText
```

If you'd rather assign the attributes in code:

```
let richText = NSMutableAttributedString()

let normalAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12) ]
let boldAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12) ]
richText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "Choose Pasta", attributes: boldAttributes))
richText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: ": Fettucine ", attributes: normalAttributes))
richText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "Add Toppings To The Pasta", attributes: boldAttributes))
richText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: ": Side Meatball ", attributes: normalAttributes))
// etc.

label.attributedText = richText
```

Comment: This is true if the UILabel text is static , but we have a dynamic UILabel where text changes. So need like "The part before : as Bold & the part after : as normal font"

Comment: Of course you can also create HTML by pasting strings together in code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u" create HTML by pasting strings together in code"

Comment: As in: `var html = "<strong>"; html += "Hello"; html += "</strong>"`, etc.