# Multiple colors in the same text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel, uitextview

I am working on an Iphone application.
Is there a way to have multiple colors in the same label or TextView?

What i mean is that I need something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this without using 3 labels?
Because the text might change dynamically and I want to have correct positionning.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible to have different style and color in single Label. Have a look at [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

Also, look at this [StackOverFlow Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869071/1603234)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) or [CoreTextAttributedLabel](https://github.com/umerh/CoreTextAttributedLabel)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 6 there is a new type of string called `NSAttributedString`.

You can change `colors`, `fonts`, `sizes`, `underline`, and almost everything for parts of a string.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I think it's only available for iOS6 or later. I haven't tested that though.