# How to create a UILabel or UITextView with bold and normal text in it?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uitextview

I am trying to create a `UILabel` or `UITextView` with bold and normal text inside.

I have gone through the attributedstring but when I am setting this in label of my custom cell it doesn't display any text.

I have also used the `UITextView setContentToHTMLString:` method, but it is undocumented and app get rejected.

Can anyone give some sort of solution to this?

Comment: wow... I've never seen a question become a "community wiki" (9 revisions in a matter of minutes) so fast!

Comment: I still don't understand why this question converted to a community wiki..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "`NSAttributedString`" to set multiple font text in a single label & use `CATextLayer` to render it:

just `#import "NSAttributedString+Attributes.h"`

and then implement it like this:

```
NSString *string1 = @"Hi";

NSString *string2 = @"How are you ?";

NSMutableAttributedString *attr1 = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:string1];

[attr1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];

NSMutableAttributedString *attr2 = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:string2]

[attr2 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];

[attr1 appendAttributedString:attr2]

CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];

layer.string = attr1;

layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

(Your_text_label).layer = textLayer;

OR (if you want to render on a view directly)

[(Your_View_Name).layer addSublayer:textLayer];
```

Answer (score 5):

Up until iOS 6.0, you couldn't do this with a normal UILabel or UITextView, but you can use NSAttributedString objects with a few possible open source solutions.

Like [TTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) or [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

One solution built into the iOS SDK, [you could also use a CATextLayer which has a string property that can be set to a NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4422701/981049).

And, like the commenters below say, yes you can do this with the ["`attributedText`" property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText).  Horray! (for Apple listening to developer's very often repeated feature requests)

Comment: Please note that UILabel is compatible with NSAttributedString with iOS 6.

Comment: You actually can do this with normal UILabels and UITextView since iOS 6 using the `attributedText` property

Comment: i am using iOS 5 and onward, does it will support in iOS 5 ?

Comment: nope, but that's why you have the other potential options I pointed out in my answer.  :-)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann thank you so much. i am trying, and if it works i'll definitely approve your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but this is something I just discovered myself. At least in Xcode version 4.6.3 this is possible by using an attributed textView. What's even better is that it's possible to all be done in Interface Builder!

Here are the steps:

Place your textView at the desired location
Select the textView and open up the Attributes tab under the Utilities panel
Change the textView text to "attributed"
Enter your desired text
Now, highlight whatever text you want bolded, underlined, etc.
Click on the "T" button next to the fontName
In the popup, select your desired typeface (ex: Bold)
You should see the desired typeface displayed in the Utilities panel
Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The following code is for iOS 6.0 and above. The result is that the text "This is bold" will be in bold and "This is not bold." will be normal text.

```
if ([self.registrationLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)])
{
    // iOS6 and above : Use NSAttributedStrings
    const CGFloat fontSize = 17;
    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    //UIColor *foregroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Create the attributes
    NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              boldFont, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    NSDictionary *subAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              regularFont, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    const NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,12); // range of " 2012/10/14 ". Ideally this should not be hardcoded

    // Create the attributed string (text + attributes)
    NSString *text = @"This is bold and this is not bold.;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                           attributes:subAttrs];
    [attributedText setAttributes:attrs range:range];

    // Set it in our UILabel and we are done!
    [self.registrationLabel setAttributedText:attributedText];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an issue with editing the attributed text in the inspector, copy/paste the text into a rich text editor, adjust it, switch the textView Text options to Attributed and paste. Vwala.