# Creating a UITextView placeholder with different colors and fonts

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitextview, placeholder

What's the best way to create a placeholder for a UITextView and the placeholder will have different colors and fonts. An example of what I want is:

```
_textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7.0, 35.0, 306.0, 90.0)];
_textView.text = @"This is a variable called foo.";
```

I want "foo" in the text to be bolder and darker in color.

How's this best done?

Comment: `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583581/how-to-keep-2-different-fonts-within-the-same-uitextfield-or-uitextview/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781506/format-text-in-uitextview

Comment: never knew about nsattributedstring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have Simple way for this .

Add `UILabel` in `UITextView` below and set `UITextView` clearColor .and set your `UILabel` text as you required and set that text color same as your requirement color . and if you click on textview then hide that label and if you clear all textview then show your placeholder label.

See this Example

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)theTextView
{
    if (![textView hasText])
    {
        lbl.hidden = NO;
    }
}

- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(![textView hasText])
    {
        lbl.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        lbl.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

I hope this idea is useful for you.

Comment: Great idea thanks! It's a shame that a ```UITextView``` doesn't just support a simple placeholder. Oh well, this solution works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to make a label and add it as the subview of your textview.
then, in the textview delegate method remove the label at the appropriate time and re-add it again when the textview's text becomes @"";

Answer (score 0):

Hi have simple solution for that,

Use GCPlaceholderTextView, where you can set placeholder text and color and font.

link for  [GCPlaceholderTextView](https://github.com/gcamp/GCPlaceholderTextView)

add in `GCPlaceholderTextView.h` file :

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIFont *placeholderFont;
```

add in `GCPlaceholderTextView.m` file :

```
- (void)setPlaceholderFont:(UIFont *)fontName {
    placeholderFont = fontName;

if ([super.text isEqualToString:self.placeholder]) {
    self.font = placeholderFont;
}
}
```