# Adding color to text in TextView

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a TextView in which I need some text to change colors and fonts. Any method is available other than core text. Please help.

Comment: do you want to change some text from all text ,right?

Comment: You should easily find answers to your problem by searching the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i need some text to change colors and fonts.

You certainly looking for [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

---

From [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring)

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello. That is a test attributed string."];
[str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(3,5)];
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(10,7)];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(20, 10)];
label.attributedText = str;
```