# 'NSAttributedString invalid for autoresizing, it must have a single spanning paragraph style (or none) with a non-wrapping lineBreakMode.'

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using given below code to add NSMutableParagraphStyle to a lable, but this code runs fine on iOS7 but gives error on iOS 6. I had also added check but still it crashes the app.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSAttributedString invalid for autoresizing, it must have a single spanning paragraph style (or none) with a non-wrapping lineBreakMode.'**

```
if ([_precherDetailLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)] && NSClassFromString(@"NSMutableParagraphStyle")!=Nil)
{
   @try {

      NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
      [paragrahStyle setLineSpacing:3];

      NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
      [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                                     value:paragrahStyle
                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
      _precherDetailLabel.attributedText=attributedString;

   }
   @catch (NSException *exception) {
       NSLog(@"exception # 2324  %@",exception);
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: i want that this method should run properly on iOS6 or it should not run due to checks, and why this error is coming

Comment: ok let me try tracing it

Comment: mate this would take time the code also works in ios6.1, i have to download the 6.0 simulator and check on that

Comment: No, its not working for me on ios 6.1

Comment: okay found the problem the i just make the autoshrink of text size for the label to fixed font then it worked

Comment: fine have a nice day ahead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
    [_precherDetailLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
```

maybe even only for iOS6

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) { //*
       [_precherDetailLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:NO];
}
```

- detect iOS 6 as decribed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html

Comment: okay found the problem the i just make the autoshrink of text size for the label to fixed font then it worked –