# Fade the end of a label text

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have one `UILabel`, and i want to fade the end of the string, that is going to be out of bounds. What is the better solution for this? 
Should i calculate the width of the label, compare it with the string width, and if string width is bigger than label's, i should fade last two letters? How exactly should i do that?
I hope it will be easy. Please write your solutions. Thanks!
I prefer to use this method for calculating the width:

```
CGRect labelRect = [text
                    boundingRectWithSize:labelSize
                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                    attributes:@{
                     NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                    }
                    context:nil];
```

Comment: briefly, masking the view with a gradient image and set `clipToBounds` to true.

Comment: I think you are looking for "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 4.0 example:

```swift
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    gradient.frame      = titleLabel.bounds
    gradient.colors     = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint   = CGPoint(x: 0.95, y: 0.0)

    label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
    label.layer.mask = gradient
```

result:

[image: result]

Comment: using a fixed 0.95 is very poor or wrong; it will be far too short in many cases

Answer (score 5):

You can fade one line label using `CAGradientLayer`

```
CAGradientLayer *l = [CAGradientLayer layer];
l.frame = self.textLabel.bounds;
l.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
l.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.1f, 1.0f);
l.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.95f, 1.0f);
self.textLabel.layer.mask = l;
```

[image: Sample fade label]

Comment: I am trying to do this in button but not able to do this. Could you please check?

Comment: using a fixed 0.95 is very poor or wrong; it will be far too short in many cases

Answer (score 0):

Works only from layoutSubviews() method

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let maskLayer = CALayer()
    maskLayer.frame = label.bounds

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = label.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.7, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.95, y: 0.0)

    maskLayer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    label.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Comment: completely wrong. it will add the new layers every time!

Answer (score 0):

Simple subclass of UILabel. It uses same ideas as in previous answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47306672/286361), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24366936/286361), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56621192/286361).
I just created complete class which updates fading on properties change.

```
class FadeTruncateLabel: UILabel {

    var fadeStart = 0.85 {
        didSet { _updateGradient() }
    }

    var fadeEnd = 1.0 {
        didSet { _updateGradient() }
    }

    lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = { return CAGradientLayer() }()

    lazy var maskLayer: CALayer = {
        let _maskLayer = CALayer()
        _maskLayer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        return _maskLayer
    }()

    override var textColor: UIColor! {
        didSet { _updateGradient() }
    }

    override var text: String? {
        didSet { _updateFading() }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        _updateFading()
    }

    private var _isTruncated: Bool {
       frame.width < intrinsicContentSize.width
    }

    private func _updateFading() {
        if _isTruncated {
            lineBreakMode = .byClipping
            if gradientLayer.colors == nil {
                _updateGradient()
            }
            gradientLayer.frame = bounds
            maskLayer.frame = bounds
            layer.mask = maskLayer
        } else {
            layer.mask = nil
        }
    }

    private func _updateGradient() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [textColor.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: fadeStart, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: fadeEnd, y: 0.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### 2023. Typical OUTLINE solution:

It **does not take in to account language direction, it assumes background is white**, etc etc.

Note that you have to explicitly decide on and set the length of the fade, which, of course, will be constant through out the app, you can't use ".1 of the width of the text". Here we use the height of the label which works well.

```
class FadeyLabel: UIILabel {
    
    lazy var fade: CAGradientLayer = {
        let g = CAGradientLayer()
        g.colors = [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor,
            UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1).cgColor]
        g.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        g.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        layer.addSublayer(g)
        return g
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        fade.frame = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - bounds.height, y: 0),
            size: CGSize(width: bounds.height, height: bounds.height))
    }
}
```