# customize UILabel like instragram

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, instagram

profilename1 commented on profilename2.

My output should above like this.

I used UILabel.

My query is profilename1 and profilename2 are in greencolor and must be clickable.

When user click profilename1 after profileviewcontroller loading.I used storyboard.

Uilabel placed in custom table cell.

How should implement this in my app ? Is it possible ?

Source : In instragram when user click on username/profilename in blue color same behavior I will implement.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `NSAttributedString` for the color and font changed need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3869071/4657588

Comment: I already know but username range always not fix

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSAttributedString` but assuming you'd rather an easier more personalized solution you could try using: [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel). I've seen it used on multiple occasions for pretty much this exact purpose.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use exact use?