# Set part of a UILabel's text bold and another part italic

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, text-styling

Is there a way to set part of a `UILabel` to be bold and another part italic?

As in

> The *quick brown* fox **jumps over** the lazy dog.

It doesn't seem I can do this using [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel)

Comment: try using attributed string.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786528/iphone-ipad-how-exactly-use-nsattributedstring

Comment: use [NSAttributedString](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3482374/1066828)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using **NSMutableAttributedString**

```
NSMutableAttributedString *strText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Setting different for label text"];
[strText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:22]
              range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
[strText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Italic" size:22]
              range:NSMakeRange(10, 10)];
```

**Swift 4 code:**

```
var strText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Setting different for label text")
strText.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 22)!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 10))
strText.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Italic", size: 22)!, range: NSRange(location: 10, length: 10))
```

Comment: Really!? There is no efficiency method to do this? Range?! and If I have a string where I have html tags?I must to build a method to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Since iOS 6 you can set `UILabel.attributedText` to an `NSAttributedString`

```
var customString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "my String");

customString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15), range: NSRange(1...3))

var label  = UILabel();
label.attributedText = customString;
```